# how to import Git project to TFS Cloud

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I visited our Team Foundation Service page and found a great new feature:

***New Team Project + Git***

This is great news. We have Projects in Team Foundation Service AND Git. Not as much because I love Git. I was very impressed with it's functionality, but never comfortable with its interface. That said, Git is an accepted standard for Open Source and I love the idea of being able to admin my Git Repos through TFS. Getting the best of both worlds (I hope).

I was able to create a Test Project in Git and am excited.

**Problem:** for all the site searching, googling, poking, prodding, I can't figure out how to import an ***existing*** Git Project into TFS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I push my existing Git repository to Team Foundation Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128541/how-can-i-push-my-existing-git-repository-to-team-foundation-service)

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh, how would this question be a duplicate of a question that was asked a month later? In fact, you should check the comment at top which marks the other question as a dupe of this one.

Comment: That's more or less standard practice. Timing does not matter. That other question asks the same thing and has a (subjectively) better answer. In my opinion it's this question that is better be closed as a duplicate of the other newer one.

Comment: For example see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Set your remote and push.

1. Make sure you enable alternate credentials in Team Foundation Service.
2. Set your remote:  `git remote add <name> <url>`,

   e.g. `git remote add origin https://yourname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/ProjectName`
3. Push it:  `git push <remote name> <name of branch>`, 
   e.g. `git push origin branchname`

Comment: Any idea why after following yoru answer i would run into: `fatal: https://yourname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

Comment: That error message means your URL is wrong - double check it against the instructions on the service!

Comment: It's also worth noticing the warning in TFS: "To clone and use this repository from Git tools outside Visual Studio, you need to ensure alternate credentials are enabled in the Profile dialog."

Comment: You may get in trouble with large repos (> 5 GB). I our case we had to push to a private gitlab repo, then import via Azure web import form pointing to the new gitlab repo.

Comment: @EdwardThomson i'm getting error of "The requested URL returned error: 500" with this format "http://tfs_server_name:8080/tfs/CollectionName/_git/ProjectName/". Is there any other specific format which should provided?