# Import existing TFS project to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: cloud, azure-devops

I found that there is opportunity to [push changes to Team Services from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630161/how-to-import-git-project-to-tfs-cloud). But i did not find any information how to make import from normal TFS 2012 to Team Services. 
Is there any chance to do it?

P.S. I found article [Migrating from an On-Premises Team Foundation Server to Visual Studio Team Services Using the TFS Integration Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx).
Now will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions in order to make migration

1. First : It's recommended to use TFS Integration Tools
2. You can also use Team Explorer and Addin Excel in order to make just migration of your Workitems, firslty you extract all WIs to Excell sheet and secondly reconnect to cloud and set import from sheet to Cloud.

Remarks : The second solution is fast & easy without configuration but not complete (Not dedicated for source code).
The first treat all datas but requires configuration